# LawPay (Payment Gateway) Integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway

Anyone have idea about Law-pay integration method. this is a payment gateway just like Paypal but i am configuring it first time so looking for some help about this gateway.i tried but not reached at any successful point.

NOTE(I am using PHP language although it is not a necessary that which language i am using, we can use any language but point is that how can i configure Law-pay gateway ?)

This is site of that gateway:

https://www.lawpay.com

Comment: Have you tried contacting LawPay for support, or at least API documentation?

Comment: there is no reference about API at there website, today i used contact form to get help about it but still not get any response from them

Comment: LawPay Offers two types of Integration. 1. via REST API and 2. WHTML/with  Callaback.  Every LawPay customer has a payment page URL. From your app, redirect to that URL with parameters to prefill the page.  There is a Reference field where you can add some identifiers to identify this transaction in your code. When someone makes a payment through that page, LawPay server makes a call to a preconfigured API method in your code and pass on payment information including the reference code you had set. You may use that reference code to process the payment in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Law-pay Payment Gateway upgraded it's payment system, so far for Integration we need to talk with them directly via there email , developers team of law-pay help to complete all area of integration

I personally contact him and spent couple of days with team and completed this Gateway on my client Site